# How to use struct in POSIX shared memory?

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I want my POSIX shared memory segment to conform to a particular structure. I think this code creates the shared memory segment in the shape of the struct.

```
(File creating the shared memory segment)

typedef struct {
  int cnt;
  char buf[segsize];
} shmseg_t;

int shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(shmseg_t);
void* addr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shmseg_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
```

How do I write data from a file to the different fields of the struct in the shared memory?

```
(File writing to the shared memory segment)

int shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_WRONLY, 0);
ftruncate(shm_fd, segsize);
void* addr = mmap(NULL, segsize, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
// How do I get shmp, which should be a shmseg_t struct?
shmp->cnt = read(fd, shmp->buf, segsize);
```

And how do I get out the data that was written to the struct in the shared memory?

```
(File reading from the shared memory segment)

int shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDONLY, 0);
ftruncate(shm_fd, segsize);
void* addr = mmap(NULL, segsize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
// How to get out shmp->cnt and shmp->buf?
```

Comment: seems that you're asking 2 quite distinct questions - how to marshal and unmarshal your struct to/from a file, and how to interact with the shared memory.  Might those be better expressed as distinct SO question posts?

Comment: I removed the second question about how to share the `shmseg_t` struct's typedef.

Comment: Why do you call `ftruncate` in three different places? Isn't the shared memory area a fixed size?

Comment: Have you tried `shmp = addr;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear whether you want to share the entire structure or just `buf`.

**Option 1:** Make `buf` a pointer, and share what it points to.

```
typedef struct {
  int cnt;
  char *buf;
} shmseg_t;

ftruncate(shm_fd, segsize);
void* addr = mmap(NULL, segsize,
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
assert(addr != MAP_FAILED);

shm_seg_t shmp = {
    .cnt = ???,  // Whatever value of cnt you want.
    .buf = addr,
};
```

**Option 2:** Share the entire struct.

```
typedef struct {
  int cnt;
  char buf[segsize];
} shmseg_t;

ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(shmseg_t));
void* addr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shmseg_t),
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
assert(addr != MAP_FAILED);

shm_seg_t *shmp = addr;
```

If you share it this way, reading and writing are not really different (but you do need to use memory barriers or synchronization).

Comment: I want to share the entire structure, `shmp->cnt` is how many bytes were read from the file with file descriptor `fd` into `shmp->buf`.

Comment: @bard: That’s “option 2”.

Comment: Don't use `assert` for error-checking that are not logical errors in your code.

Comment: @HAL9000: I spent a moment thinking about how to acknowledge that you should check the result from `mmap`, and my thought was, “I want to make it clear that you should check the result from `mmap`, but I don’t want to introduce a lot of extra code into my answer that does error handling correctly, because that will make the code snippet longer and less clear. The `assert` function is the shortest, and clearest way to do that, and I will use that. It is not appropriate to have an entire discussion about error handling here, so I will trust people to do the right thing.”

Comment: @HAL9000: I was worried that someone would make a comment like yours, and I guess my fears were justified. In the future I may decide to write less clear, more weasel-worded answers just so I can avoid having this conversation again.

Comment: And anyway, just don’t define NDEBUG. It’s fine.